# Math homework, so much guessing work?

Tags: geometry

Riki hires a digger to load topsoil onto his trailer. The bottom of the trailer is square with sides 1.5 meters long. The height of the sides of the trailer is 25 centimeters. The digger shovel holds 0.25 cubic meters of topsoil.

He loads three shovels full of topsoil into the trailer. The soil fills the trailer completely, and heaps up so that pile is higher in the muddle than it is at the sides.

How high above the sides of the trailer will three shovels full of soil reach?

---

The answers are explained as such:

Volume of cuboid = 1.5 * 1.5 * .25 = .5625 m3

Volume of three shovels full = .75 m3

Volume of pyramid = volume of three shovels full - volume of cuboid = .1875 m3

If h is the height of the pyramid, then

1/3 * base height * h = .1875

1/3 * 1.5 * 1.5 * h = .1875

h = .25

Three shovels full of soil will reach .25 meters above the sides of the trailer.

---

I understand the initial work, but don't understand how they got .25 as the height above the trailer. There's no other explanation in my work book. It just seems like guessing work to me.

I'm going to fail my exam if I don't understand this.

Comment: The solution presented in the book is correct and actually quite nicely spelled out. What is the first line that you don't understand?

Comment: It's well explained. The only thing that was not totally obvious is that the topsoil that is not inside the trailer takes the shape of a pyramid

Comment: "If h is the height of the pyramid, then" - It baffles me how they inferred that h = .25m (25 centimeters). I apologize, I'm hopeless when it comes to mathematics.

Comment: No, it's fine. This is not a straightforward problem. Just to be clear: you are confused about going from line 4 to 5? or is it from line 6 to 7?

Comment: I'm confused about going from line 6 to 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has stated that eir primary confusion with the solution provided is the implication

> $$\frac13\cdot(1.5)\cdot (1.5) \cdot h = .1875 \qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad h=0.25$$

Simplifying the right side of line 6:

$$\frac13\cdot(1.5)\cdot (1.5) \cdot h ~=~ \frac13\cdot\frac32\cdot\frac32\cdot h ~=~ \frac34 h$$

Also note that $.1875=\frac3{16}$. (This isn't obvious but if you had used fraction notation the entire time then you would already have it as a fraction, so I'll just pretend we did)

Therefore, multiply both sides by 4 and divide both sides by 3 to get
$$\frac43\cdot\frac34 h = \frac43\cdot\frac3{16}$$
Cross-cancelling gets the final answer:
$$h = \frac14 = 0.25.$$

Answer (score 0):

$1/3*1.5*1.5*h=.1875$

$1/3*1.5*1.5=.75$

$.75*h=.1875$

Divide both sides by $.75$

$\frac{.75*h}{.75}=\frac{.1875}{.75}$

$h=\frac{.1875}{.75}=.25$